# Bourbon Install Error: "bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby, windows, bash, sass, bourbon

I am new to Sass and RubyGems. I have installed Sass and it is functioning as expected. I want to now install the Bourbon library for use in my project, however, I keep getting an error that says `"D:/Program: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"`.

I have tried `bourbon install` and `bourbon install --path /custom/path/here`, but keep getting the same error. I check my `gem -v` and navigated to my Ruby install directory and everything seems fine. Inside of `../Ruby26-x64/bin` there are all the Bourbon files and the Thor files.

Help. I don't know what's wrong.

System: Windows 10 Enterprise

Bash: Git Bash

Ruby: 3.0.3

Comment: Sounds like a classic Windows issue of not having escaped spaces in `Program Files` folder. Sadly I don't have any experience with `bourbon` so not sure what to do about that.

Comment: That was the exact issue, and it wasn't only an issue with ```bourbon```, it was an issue with more ```Ruby``` gems as well. To prevent this from happening in the future, because I will be using ```Ruby``` and more gems/libraries, my solution was to uninstall any program/language, create a new folder simply named ```programs``` and reinstall in that location.

I'm sure there is a different solution, like maybe configuring the interpreter to escape spaces in file path names, but I wasn't sure how to do that.

Comment: That’s a good idea. I’ve also seen Ruby install itself in `C:/Ruby24/` for this reason.